# Array of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, swift

Can't seem to find the right syntax. Trying to get an array of dicts from a json file:

```
let books:Array = jsonDict["books"] as Array
//Cannot convert the expression's type Array<$T4> to type StringLiteralConvertible

let books:Array = jsonDict["books"] as Array<Dictionary>
//Reference to generic type "Dicionary" requires arguments in <...>
```

The json looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "title one",
  "books": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "book title one"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "book title two"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `Array<Dictionary<String, String>>`?

Comment: wow, that's ugly. but ok...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you specify an Array, you have to also be specific and list what is in the Array. You also need

What you're probably looking for is:

```
let books = jsonDict["books"]
```

The compiler should be able to infer what's in there. If not, you can cast using:

```
let books = jsonDict["books"] as Array<Dictionary<String, String>>
```

Having the type cast *and* the type specifier for books is unnecessary.

Comment: I certainly would prefer the first one, and it seems to work. However I get a warning: Constant 'books' inferred to have type 'AnyObject', which may be unexpected.

Comment: Right, in that case, definitely use the second one. It's probably because `jsonDict` has type of `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` or something similar that would give you an `AnyObject`.

Comment: Does it work with Swift 2 as well? (I got error `'String?' is not convertible to 'Array<Dictionary<String, String>>')`

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2, typecasting as below works !

[[String: AnyObject]]

I tested with the example

```
-{
"city" : +{ ... },
"cod" : 200,
"message" : 0.0068,
"cnt" : 6,
"list" : -[
-{
"dt" : 1461369600,
"main" : +{ ... },
"weather" : +[ ... ],
"clouds" : +{ ... },
"wind" : +{ ... },
"rain" : +{ ... },
"sys" : +{ ... },
"dt_txt" : 2016-04-23 00:00:00
},
+{ ... },
+{ ... },
+{ ... },
+{ ... },
+{ ... }
]
}
```

The swift code is deduced as below

```
let theJSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(theData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]

let theList = theJSONData["list"] as! [[String: AnyObject]] // Array of Dictionaries
let dayOneWeather = theList[0]
let mainDayOneWeather = dayOneWeather["main"] as! [String:AnyObject]
let dayOneTemperature = mainDayOneWeather["temp"] as! Int
let dayOneTemperatureInDegreeCelsius = dayOneTemperature - 273
```